# Fazer Select com procura de valor em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo uma tabela com campos de chave estrangeira, e gostaria de retornar em um `select` o valor do item para a chave.

Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte tabela formada com a query:

```
SELECT cod_produto,
MQ1FK,
MQ2FK,
MQ3FK,
MQ4FK,
MQ5FK
FROM engenharia_processo 
INNER JOIN engenharia_produto 
ON cod_produto = codigo;

    cod_produto     MQ1FK  MQ2FK  MQ3FK  MQ4FK  MQ5FK
    0101500063500   18     5       null   null  null
    0101500083500   1      3       4      null  null
```

Em outra tabela  possuo os dados:

```
    MQPK | Valor
    1      2
    3      5
    4      3
    5      9
    18     7
```

Gostaria de realizar uma consulta que retornasse a tabela com o campo Valor no lugar da chave, tipo:

```
cod_produto     MQ1FK  MQ2FK  MQ3FK  MQ4FK  MQ5FK
0101500063500   7      9       null   null  null
0101500083500   2      5       3      null  null
```

Tentei usar:

```
select valor from engenharia_maquina where MQPK = (select MQ1FK from engenharia_processo);
```

Porem como o retorno possui mais de uma linha não da certo.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Você pode fazer um inner join no seu select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você garantir que o relacionamento é de 1 para 1, ou seja, há apenas um MQPK para cada MQ1FK, deve bastar adicionar TOP 1 na subconsulta:

```
select valor from engenharia_maquina where MQPK = (select TOP 1 MQ1FK from engenharia_processo);
```

Caso contrario, o que você precisa é de um Join. Você terá múltiplas ocorrências dos dados da tabela principal, pois esses dados serão repetidos para cada linha da tabela com chave estrangeira - então talvez você queira uma consulta só para a tabela principal, e uma consulta separada só para os dados da tabela "filha". Algo do tipo:

```
SELECT
    engenharia_processo.cod_produto,
    engenharia_maquina.valor
FROM engenharia_maquina
INNER JOIN engenharia_processo
    ON engenharia_maquina.MQPK = engenharia_processo.ID
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.